# Android: Give every checkbox in the listview a listener without overwriting the others

Tags: android, listener

Because my listView/List items have checkboxes I have the problem, that checkboxes are checked or unchecked when I'm scrolling through the list. Therefore I need to track checked items in a ArrayList for example. So I added an OnCheckedChangeListener on each checkbox and I've added the listener in the "getView" from the custom adapter for the listview.

Now since every checbox react on the click I have the following problem.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    
...
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                if (!MainActivity.getSharedInstance().getIsCheckedArray().contains(tasks.get(MainActivity.ID)))
                    MainActivity.getSharedInstance().getIsCheckedArray().add(tasks.get(MainActivity.ID));
                for (String i : MainActivity.getSharedInstance().getIsCheckedArray()) {
                    Log.i("RUN", i);
                }
            } else {
                if (MainActivity.getSharedInstance().getIsCheckedArray().contains(tasks.get(MainActivity.ID)))
                    MainActivity.getSharedInstance().getIsCheckedArray().remove(tasks.get(MainActivity.ID));
                for (String i : MainActivity.getSharedInstance().getIsCheckedArray()) {
                    Log.i("RUN", i);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

From each list item I have an own ID and I can reach the item with that ID. But when I click on the checkboxes to get the ID, I only get the ID of one item ( the last item ). When I click on the other checkboxes they react to the change but I only get the ID from the last item and not from the items before the last one.

Do I overwrite the listeners when I always create the new Listener?

**Update:**
Nevermind, I added this to the onCheckChangeListener

```
String curIndex = tasks.get(MainActivity.ID);
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think your mistake is, that You doesn´t use a LayoutInflater. Just try:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourListViewItemLayout, parent,false);

    final Checkbox yourCheckBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBoxId);
             yourCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener......
```

this should work